# Thread safe hooking of DirectX Device

Tags: com, thread-safety, directx, hook, vtable

I successfully hooked BeginScene/EndScene methods of DirectX9's DeviceEx, in order to override regions on the screen of a graphics application. I did it by overriding the first 'line' of the function pointed by the appropriate vtable entry (42 for EndScene) with an x86 jump command.

The problem is that when I would like to call the original EndScene method, I have to write the original code overriden by the jump. This operation is not thread safe, and the application has two devices used by two threads.

I tried overriding the vtable entry or copying it and override the COM interface pointer to the vtable, neither ways worked. I guess the original function pointer is cached somewhere or was optimized in the compilation.

I thought about copying the whole original method body to another memory block, but two problems I'm afraid of: (1) (the easy one I think) I don't know how to discover the length of the method and (2) I don't know if the function body stores offsets which are relative to the location where the function is in memory.

I'm trying to hook WPF's device, if it can help somehow.

Do anyone know a thread safe way for such hooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: It seems that for my purpose (performing another method before or instead of the original one within my own process), 'trampoline' is the answer. Generally it means I need to make another code segment that makes exactly what the overriden assembly commands did.

Because it is not an easy task, using an external library is recommended.

A discussion about this topic:
[How to create a trampoline function for hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334560/how-to-create-a-trampoline-function-for-hook)